# How to reproduce batched mutations from MutationObserver in `contenteditable`?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, mutation-observers

This is a bit of an arcane question but if someone with an answer exists, they're probably here.

I am trying to mirror an element. The idea is to have a function `mirrorElement`, pass an HTML element to it (the source element), and have it return a new element (the mirror element) that will be a clone of the source, and will keep reflecting changes made to the source.

I am using `MutationObserver` to watch the source and change the mirror based on the observed mutations. I maintain a node `Map` which associates each descendent of the source with its counterpart in the mirror.

- If a node is removed, I look up the reference in the node map and remove it from the mirror as well
- If a node is added, I copy it and add it to the mirror in the right spot (and add it and its descendents to the node map) by looking up its parent in the node map
- I do the same for attribute & text changes

This may be irrelevant to the core of my question but it gives some background on how I'm approaching the problem.

This technique works wonderfully, as long as there are no `contenteditable` elements. If the changes to the `contenteditable` elements are simple - like typing or pasting raw text - the algorithm can handle it. However, when I try to drag and drop or paste multi line text or HTML, everything falls apart. Here is why.

`MutationObserver` passes a `mutationsList` to its callback. Usually, that `mutationsList` has a lenght of `1`, representing a single mutation. With a single mutation, I can simply look up the `mutation.target` in my node map and reflect the mutation in the mirror, as I described earlier. I have tested many different ways of mutating the DOM and I have not yet found a single one that produced a `mutationsList` longer than `1` - other than dragging or pasting HTML into a `contenteditable` element. Consider this example.

```js
new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  document.getElementById('length').textContent = mutationsList.length;
}).observe(document.getElementById('editor'), {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
});
```

```html
<p>Mutations: <span id="length"></span></p>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"><span>Paste or drag HTML here</span></div>
<hr>
<p>Sample HTML content</p>
<div style="background-color:purple">
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
<p>baz</p>
```

Try dragging or pasting some of the sample HTML into the `contenteditable` in different positions. This can produce upwards of 30 mutations in Chrome, some of which can be truly bizarre - elements are added in one mutation only to be removed in the next, they get assigned strange inline styles. If you copy and paste a part of this question, the number of mutations can exceed 150. And finally, here is why that's a problem.

When multiple mutations are observed at the same time, the elements referenced in the `MutationRecord`s have in some cases already been mutated by further mutations in the same batch, which makes it impossible to mirror them properly. The records sometimes contain references to nodes that have had their children removed by further mutations, or the nodes themselved may no longer be present on the `mutation.target` (or in the DOM at all, for that matter) because a further mutation removed them, or their attributes may have been mutated. Finally, Chrome appears to add an empty text node to new elements (without a mutation record), and that would be easy to take into account (by adding an empty text node to copies) if it weren't for the fact that it often removes it a few mutations later, which prevents me getting a reference to it.

I've considered and implemented some potential solutions, but all of them have severe downsides:

1. Reconstructing the entire mirror whenever any mutation happens. Not very performant.
2. Reversing the `mutationsList`, applying the mutations to the source backwards, and reapplying them again in the correct order to both the source and the mirror. This works, but it mutates the source, which is something I can't accept (since other code may be relying on its contents or attributes).
3. Ignoring mutations on `contenteditable` descendents and reconstructing the entire `contenteditable` element on the mirror whenever a mutation happens. This appears to work, however I am worried about the computational overhead as well as batched mutations happening in other situations (perhaps on faster or slower systems).

I'm looking for an idea on how to approach this - how to reconstruct the effect of the mutations if they contain effectively broken references? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: If there's multiple mutations in the list, it should be possible to find the lowest common ancestor of all the mutated nodes, then clone/reconstruct only that (not the entire contenteditable div).

Comment: I did not think of that, I'll try implementing it. Thanks!

Comment: Any time multiple mutations are performed in the same task you will have multiple mutation events. For instance you can do `for (let i = 0; i<300; i++) {
 elem.setAttribute("foo", i%2); }` and it will generate 300 mutation events. Regarding what you are doing, I'm not sure what would be the best... For instance Bergi's solution might create a big overhead if two nodes are modified in the same task but only have the root element as common ancestor. Firefox has an `element()` css <image> which may be just what you need, but I don't think it's polyfilable, and it may not be what you need either.

Comment: @Kaiido There is one exception - `contenteditable` elements, when you copy and paste or drag things into them (specifically HTML content) then multiple mutations may be observed in the same event. You can verify that with the snippet I posted, just copy and paste some HTML and look as the number of mutations.

Comment: The `element()` solution would be great but I'm also mirroring events (from the mirror to the source). I omitted that in the question to narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: You probably misread my comment. I'm saying that having multiple mutations per event is not an exception. It can happen with very common codes (it should actually happen in most well written codes since batching all mutations together should be preferred in general). And for the events thing it's not too hard to redispatch mouseevents where you want, but given the bad support of `element()` I'm not sure it's worth the pain.